# How do you extract registered variables returned from an ansible playbook?

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-api

I have a playbook task like this:

```
tasks:

  - shell: /usr/bin/foo
    register: foo_result
```

I'm running this playbook using the python API, and I would like to do some post processing on the `foo_result` variable.  How do I access `foo_result` using the API?

Comment: I have no experience with the API yet but I know the API has changed between Ansible 1 and 2. It might be worth adding your Ansible version to the question so you get an answer that will work for you.

Comment: Does [how to make a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39991404/6771046) answer your question?