# How to get remote stdout from Ansible python playbook api

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-2.x

I know I can print the std out using the `debug` module of Ansible like below:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: list files under /root folder
    command: ls /root
    register: out

  - name: stdout
    debug: var=out.stdout_lines
```

And from the answer of [How to use Ansible 2.0 Python API to run a Playbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35368044/how-to-use-ansible-2-0-python-api-to-run-a-playbook), I can run Ansible playbook with python code.

So the question is how can I get the content of the variable `out` in this playbook using Ansible python api?

Comment: Have you inspected `results` value from the answer you mention?

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov I've inspected it. The `result` is just a number, maybe means the status of the task.

Comment: Do you want stdout_lines or stdout?

Comment: Either stdout_lines or stdout is OK. I think the variable `out` here may contain both of them.

Answer (score 6):

here is my answers, you should make a `callback`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json
from ansible.parsing.dataloader import DataLoader
from ansible.vars import VariableManager
from ansible.inventory import Inventory
from ansible.playbook.play import Play
from ansible.executor.task_queue_manager import TaskQueueManager
from ansible.executor.playbook_executor import PlaybookExecutor

from ansible.plugins import callback_loader
from ansible.plugins.callback import CallbackBase

import os
import logging


loader = DataLoader()
variable_manager = VariableManager()
inventory = Inventory(loader=loader, variable_manager=variable_manager)
variable_manager.set_inventory(inventory)

#get result output
class ResultsCollector(CallbackBase):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ResultsCollector, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.host_ok = []
        self.host_unreachable = []
        self.host_failed = []

    def v2_runner_on_unreachable(self, result, ignore_errors=False):
        name = result._host.get_name()
        task = result._task.get_name()
        ansible_log(result)
        #self.host_unreachable[result._host.get_name()] = result
        self.host_unreachable.append(dict(ip=name, task=task, result=result))

    def v2_runner_on_ok(self, result,  *args, **kwargs):
        name = result._host.get_name()
        task = result._task.get_name()
        if task == "setup":
            pass
        elif "Info" in task:
            self.host_ok.append(dict(ip=name, task=task, result=result))
        else:
            ansible_log(result)
            self.host_ok.append(dict(ip=name, task=task, result=result))

    def v2_runner_on_failed(self, result,   *args, **kwargs):
        name = result._host.get_name()
        task = result._task.get_name()
        ansible_log(result)
        self.host_failed.append(dict(ip=name, task=task, result=result))

class Options(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = "smart"
        self.forks = 10
        self.check = False
        self.become = None
        self.become_method = None
        self.become_user=None
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return None

options = Options()


def run_adhoc(ip,order):
    variable_manager.extra_vars={"ansible_ssh_user":"root" , "ansible_ssh_pass":"passwd"}
    play_source = {"name":"Ansible Ad-Hoc","hosts":"%s"%ip,"gather_facts":"no","tasks":[{"action":{"module":"command","args":"%s"%order}}]}
#    play_source = {"name":"Ansible Ad-Hoc","hosts":"192.168.2.160","gather_facts":"no","tasks":[{"action":{"module":"command","args":"python ~/store.py del"}}]}   
    play = Play().load(play_source, variable_manager=variable_manager, loader=loader)
    tqm = None
    callback = ResultsCollector()

    try:
        tqm = TaskQueueManager(
            inventory=inventory,
            variable_manager=variable_manager,
            loader=loader,
            options=options,
            passwords=None,
            run_tree=False,
        )
        tqm._stdout_callback = callback
        result = tqm.run(play)
        return callback

    finally:
        if tqm is not None:
            tqm.cleanup()

def run_playbook(books):
    results_callback = callback_loader.get('json')
    playbooks = [books]

    variable_manager.extra_vars={"ansible_ssh_user":"root" , "ansible_ssh_pass":"passwd"}
    callback = ResultsCollector()

    pd = PlaybookExecutor(
        playbooks=playbooks,
        inventory=inventory,
        variable_manager=variable_manager,
        loader=loader,
        options=options,
        passwords=None,

        )
    pd._tqm._stdout_callback = callback

    try:
        result = pd.run()
        return callback

    except Exception as e:
        print e

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #run_playbook("yml/info/process.yml")

    #run_adhoc("192.168.2.149", "ifconfig")
```