# Ansible get return value from tasks execution with Python Api

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-api

Is there a way to get the return values from the execution of a module?

For example https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ec2_vpc_subnet_module.html

To get for example the vpc_id.

I am  using the PlaybookExecutor but it only returns the status result of executing the playbook.

Comment: Does [how to make a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39991404/6771046) answer your question?